# Daily SQL Server Database update / Import

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I need your opinions for few things which is heavy for me.

1)  I need help with:  At the moment I am making setup SSIS for automatized daily import .txt file into MS SQL server.
Every day I need made refresh of phone book. (Sometimes information’s get change, ID over name never , but sometimes someone leave job or new guy start)

Every day I will get new txt. file Which I will by SSIS import in to SQL server.

Problem is : How I will get know which ID of employee is new or which employee was exist yesterday and which employee ID gone..

For this I get Idea : I want to made 1 permanent column which will keep values as- NEW , OLD ,STAY. But How to fix 1 extra column in to database when every morning will be overwrite.. Solution should be triggers, but how they will compare data if previous table was overwrite.

2)  That txt file is zipped. I need 1) download it (WGET)+2)Unzip (DO not know)+Import to SQL server (SSIS) + get know who LEFT/STAY/NEW (Triggers???)

Thank you for your opinions guys..

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I am guessing you might want to look at MERGE but from what you have posted it is just too vague to know for sure.

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and MS SQL Server here?!?

Comment: MS SQL 2012 + Windows Server 2012 R2 + Win7

Comment: You seem to be asking a few questions here. Try picking one question to ask well. Then, when you get an answer, and have that bit working, you can ask a new question for the next stage.

Comment: Well you will have to establish a "primary key" for each contact. That maybe a unique identifier already existing in the import file or you may need to use a combination of columns such as first name, last name and phone number. Or just phone number. Whatever it is, you will have to establish the rules. Then you can use this unique identifier to compare and update existing contacts and insert new ones.